# AssertionError "not called" on simple mock in Python

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to use the Python mock module (downloaded using pip) for the first time. I'm having problems setting an assert, I've narrowed it down to this code:

```
class TestUsingMock(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.fake_client = mock.Mock()

    def test_mock(self):
        self.fake_client.copy = mock.Mock()
        self.fake_client.copy("123")
        self.fake_client.assert_called_with("123")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This is the error I get:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_mock (__main__.TestVCSDriver)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mock_test.py", line 17, in test_mock
    self.fake_client.assert_called_with("123")
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/mock.py", line 859, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError('Expected call: %s\nNot called' % (expected,))
AssertionError: Expected call: mock('123')
Not called
```

Without the assertion, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the object `self.fake_client.copy`, but test whether another one, `self.fake_client` has been called.

Either call the "correct" object:

```
self.fake_client("123")
self.fake_client.assert_called_with("123")
```

or test the `copy`:

```
self.fake_client.copy("123")
self.fake_client.copy.assert_called_with("123")
```

Comment: Your second example was what I intended, thanks for your help!